# How to list active projects in gerrit

Tags: gerrit

We have totally **1k** gerrit projects, In that many are `Active, ReadOnly` and `Hidden`. I'm the gerrit admin and would need to list the projects are in `Active` state.

How do i list only the active project in gerrit?

I couldn't find state oriented option in this - [Link](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-ls-projects.html)

Please let me know the way to list them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Link](https://groups.google.com/g/repo-discuss/c/dWaXN5ZcJiM/m/PTcpsk1dAQAJ) has an answer.

With `ssh -p 29418 your.gerrit.host gerrit ls-projects -h` to list help options then need to look for below section.

```
--state (-s) [ACTIVE | READ_ONLY | : filter by project state
 HIDDEN]
```

With the `--state` able to list the active only projects.